# Formatted pluralize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluralize

I have a case where I need to use pluralize to properly spell something. However, I need to render the html like so:

```
<span>1</span> thing
```

or,

```
<span>3</span> things
```

I could write a helper method, but I'm just making sure there isn't something in the box to do this.

Comment: While I have agonized over this sort of thing in the past myself, I have come to believe that context sensitive pluralization is over kill. Unless you are literally generating prose, I find "1 things" or "1 thing(s)" perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Attention to detail matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interim, I've created this helper method, because it looks like there isn't what I'm looking for:

```
def pluralize_word(count, singular, plural = nil)
  ((count == 1 || count == '1') ? singular : (plural || singular.pluralize))
end
```

It's essentially identical to the pluralize method, except that it removes the number from the front. This allows me to do this (haml):

```
%span.label= things.size.to_s
%description= pluralize_word(things.size, 'thing')
```

Answer (score 6):

This uses the Rails class [TextHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001714) which uses [Inflector](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/Inflector.html#M001627) to do the pluralization if needed.

```
def pluralize_with_html(count, word)
  "<span>#{count}</span> #{TextHelper.pluralize(count, word)}"
end
```

Comment: This certainly works based on what I asked for, but I think the helper method I posted gives more flexibility to the designer in general. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to invoke YAGNI on that comment and say to refactor if you find another use.